# How to have xPath expression for more than one conditions

Tags: xml, xpath

**(Updated)**

I have something like the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ChangeTypes>
    <ChangeType Type="ItemGLStock">
        <ItemMessages>
            <ItemMessage Type="MessageType="TypeI">
                <Content MessageContentTermID="0" MessageContent="Bla Bla Bla"/>
            </ItemMessage>
            <ItemMessage Type="MessageType="TypeII">
                <Content MessageContentTermID="0" MessageContent="Bla Bla Bla"/>
            </ItemMessage>
            <ItemMessage Type="MessageType="TypeIII">
                <Content MessageContentTermID="0" MessageContent="Bla Bla Bla"/>
            </ItemMessage>
            <ItemMessage Type="MessageType="TypeIV">
                <Content MessageContentTermID="0" MessageContent="Bla Bla Bla"/>
            </ItemMessage>
        </ItemMessages>
    </ChangeType>
</ChangeTypes>
```

Now I want to use XPath to select one MessageContentTermID and MessageContent, based on ChangeType and ItemMessage Type.
Is it possible?

Comment: Since you only have one `ChangeType` it really doesn't come down to two choices, does it? Answering your question: sure it's possible. Please provide an example desired inout and output (and, preferably, your attempts).

Comment: @Jongware it is a big big file with lots of changeTypes :) I just mentioned an example here.

Comment: If this is really your input data, it's not XML at all.

Comment: yeah @CharlesDuffy, as I typed the sample in here I missed the type attribute in changeType element.

Comment: I will update the XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example input XML is not valid - I've adjusted e.g. `<ChangeType ="ItemGLStock">` to `<ChangeType Type="ItemGLStock">` and `<ItemMessage Type="MessageType="TypeI">` to `<ItemMessage MessageType="TypeI">` and changed the `ItemGLEvaluationMessage` tags which are opening but but closing and vice versa to `ItemMessage` for the following adjusted example input:

```
<ChangeTypes>
  <ChangeType Type="ItemGLStock">
    <ItemGLEvaluationMessages>
        <ItemMessage MessageType="TypeI">
            <Content MessageContentTermID="0" MessageContent="Bla Bla Bla"/>
        </ItemMessage>
        <ItemMessage MessageType="TypeII">
            <Content MessageContentTermID="0" MessageContent="Bla Bla Bla"/>
        </ItemMessage>
        <ItemMessage MessageType="TypeIII">
            <Content MessageContentTermID="0" MessageContent="Bla Bla Bla"/>
     </ItemMessage>
        <ItemMessage MessageType="TypeIV">
            <Content MessageContentTermID="0" MessageContent="Bla Bla Bla"/>
        </ItemMessage>
    </ItemGLEvaluationMessages>
  </ChangeType>
</ChangeTypes>
```

For this example, the following XPath

```
//Content[parent::ItemMessage[@MessageType="TypeI"] and
          ancestor::ChangeType[@Type='ItemGLStock']]
         /@MessageContentTermID
```

selects the `MessageContentTermID` based on two conditions:

```
parent::ItemMessage[@MessageType="TypeI"] 
and
ancestor::ChangeType[@Type='ItemGLStock']
```

Result:

```
MessageContentTermID="0"
```

For the MessageContent, it's accordingly:

```
//Content[parent::ItemMessage[@MessageType="TypeI"] and 
          ancestor::ChangeType[@Type='ItemGLStock']]
         /@MessageContent
```

Result:

```
MessageContent="Bla Bla Bla"
```

In case you only want the value, you can use `string()`:

```
string(//Content[parent::ItemMessage[@MessageType="TypeI"] and
                 ancestor::ChangeType[@Type='ItemGLStock']]
                /@MessageContent)
```

Result:

```
Bla Bla Bla
```

Comment: Yup, I should have used ancestor as well as parent. Thanks!